# Reducing collet 3/8" - 1/4"

Tags: router, router-bit

I picked up a relatively cheap plunge router that takes 3/8" however I can't seem to find any reasonably priced 3/8" shank bit kits.

I have found 1/4" and obviously it doesn't fit. Is there an adapter that would make these 1/4" fit ?

For reference the router is a [Laptronix](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Laptronix-1200w-Electric-Router-Cutter-Variable-Speed-Plunge-Joiners-Woodworking/352444693807?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3D8e50e5feb9f045b395fe4e86f371d22f%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D15%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D401694223990%26itm%3D352444693807&_trksid=p2481888.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Aafab856d-7987-11e9-9f10-74dbd180e358%7Cparentrq%3Acbb6fdf216a0ad78ed81f064fff5248a%7Ciid%3A1).

Comment: See: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/3915/5572 But, bear in mind that SE sites are terrible for ephemeral info like "where to buy", as such information will be out of date in an internet moment. Just buy 3/8in bits or replace the collet if that is both possible and safe. Remember, the primary job of a poorly configured router is to remove the meat from the operator. Don't give it any help.

Comment: Also, make sure you have what you think you have -- that linked router is metric, so this is sized for 6/8mm tools. It would be unwise in most cases to assume imperial sized tools would fit safely. If they have collet accessories it could be best to get it from the source. Otherwise, use the size of tool recommended in the manual.

Comment: Agree there's a high likelihood of metric collet, but if it isn't, google, "Amana Tool RB-108 High Precision Steel Router Collet Reducer 3/8 Overall D x 1/4 Inner D x 1 Inch Long". If it's metric, Lee Valley and many others sell 8mm>1/4" adapters.